# Unir dos consultas en una tabla (Mysqli PHP)

Tags: php, mysqli, sql, tablas

podrían orientarme en el siguiente problema por favor.

Tengo una BD con las siguientes tablas

**Tabla detalle_contrato**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla detalle_tradicional** 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se enlazan mediante `ID_CONTRATO` como se muestra y necesito mostrar una table que me muestre los siguientes datos como las consultas que mostraré a continuación:

`SELECT ID_CONTRATO,TRADICIONAL,NOM_VARIEDAD,SUM(CANTIDAD) FROM detalle_contrato WHERE ID_CONTRATO='$ID' AND TIPO_VARIEDAD='TRADICIONAL'`

`SELECT SUM(CANTIDAD_D) detalle_tradicional WHERE ID_CONTRATO='$ID' GROUP BY NOM_VARIEDAD";`

La idea es que muestre `ID_CONTRATO, NOM_VARIEDAD, CANTIDAD(DEBE SER LA SUMA DE CANTIDAD DE TODAS LAS DUKE DE LA TABLA DETALLE_CONTRATO) Y CANTIDAD_D(TABLA DETALLE_TRADICIONAL QUE ES LA SUMA DE TODAS LAS DUKE DEL CAMPO CANTIDAD_D.`

Agradecería su colaboración sobre como podría realizar la unión en `PHP` y `mysqli` para mostrar en una table.

Comment: No estoy muy fresco con las consultas hace timepo deje las bases de datos pero espero alguien te responda. Lo correcto aqui es usar `Joins`  `inner join` `left join` `rigth join` etc... si nadie te responde yo lo hago mas tarde.

Comment: lo agradeceria mucho estimado.